# How to remove the warning of the following?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When using intelliJ to compile a Java8 program, I received the error of the following

> objc[91609]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   and
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I am wondering how to fix this warning?

Comment: Closing as duplicate unless the fix in the other question does not help you.

Comment: JDK 8u121 is dated.  Try upgrading your JDK.